# Trouble using Selenium Grid/RC with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I have built a couple of test cases as stand alone python classes using Selenium. I can run each of them using Selenium RC. Ultimately I want to use Selenium Grid to run all of the test cases.

How would I do this?

Do I need some kind of wrapper to hold of of the python test cases together? How do I get Selenium Grid to run a collection of these?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at running your tests in Parallel using [Nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/)

There is documentation on how to get it running [here](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html)

Comment: Both of the links are dead - may you update the links AND put in your answer the quoted solution text?